# Handling extended Latin characters in URLs correctly with PHP and percent-encoding

Tags: url, php, url-encoding

I am currently tying myself up in knots over URL percent-encoding of extended Latin characters.

---

## Step 1 of 4

I have the following URL:

```
https://example.com/fußgängerbrücke/
```

The offline folder name (which I have uploaded via FTP) exactly corresponds to this: `fußgängerbrücke`

---

## Step 2 of 4

Wherever this URL has an internal link pointing to it anywhere on the site, the link now takes the percent-encoded form:

```
<a href="/fu%C3%9Fg%C3%A4ngerbr%C3%BCcke/">
```

If I cut and paste the URL from the URL bar in Firefox, it pastes as: `fu%C3%9Fg%C3%A4ngerbr%C3%BCcke`

---

## Step 3 of 4

**But...** imagine that URL is a referrer to the current page.

If I now use PHP to grab the URL (and edit it a little):

```
$My_Reference = str_replace('https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$My_Reference = explode('?', $My_Reference)[0];
$My_Reference = substr($My_Reference, 1, -1);
```

and then later, I use `$My_Reference` to retrieve some related data:

```
file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$My_Reference.'/my-data.php');
```

it doesn't work.

I had a think about this and concluded that this might be what's happening:

- `file_get_contents()` is (somehow?) detecting the extended Latin characters in `$My_Reference` and parsing `fußgängerbrücke` as `fu%C3%9Fg%C3%A4ngerbr%C3%BCcke`. (Can this be right?)
- It then looks for a folder which literally exists as `/fu%C3%9Fg%C3%A4ngerbr%C3%BCcke/` and can't find it, because the only folder that exists is `/fußgängerbrücke/`

So, to test this hypothesis, I tried:

```
file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].urldecode($My_Reference).'/my-data.php');
```

which ***does work*** (hooray!), but... well, it seems weird.

I felt uncomfortable about this, since I'm not trying (and don't need) to decode percent-encoded URLs anywhere else on the site, in any other context, and this just makes for a weird exception. For the sake of consistency, I'd just rather use **percent-encoding everywhere**.

---

## Step 4 of 4

So... I went back to the original offline folder and renamed it from

```
fußgängerbrücke
```

to

```
fu%C3%9Fg%C3%A4ngerbr%C3%BCcke
```

and then uploaded it and replaced the old folder.

Guess what...? *The new URL doesn't resolve!*

Instead, I get a `404`, now.

Presumably because the server is now automatically decoding the hardcoded percent-encoding and trying to find the folder `/fußgängerbrücke/` in the webspace... which isn't there.

**In summary:**

If I upload a folder named `fußgängerbrücke`:

- `example.com/fußgängerbrücke` resolves to `/fußgängerbrücke/index.php`
- `/fu%C3%9Fg%C3%A4ngerbr%C3%BCcke` resolves to `/fußgängerbrücke/index.php`

Whereas if I upload a folder named `fu%C3%9Fg%C3%A4ngerbr%C3%BCcke`:

- `/fußgängerbrücke` goes to a `404`
- `/fu%C3%9Fg%C3%A4ngerbr%C3%BCcke` goes to a `404`

---

So what am I missing here? Two questions:

- Does `file_get_contents()` automatically percent-encode extended Latin characters which then need to be explicitly percent-decoded again?
- Is it impossible to have URL foldernames and filenames which have percent-encoding already hardcoded into them?

Comment: I've checked my .htaccess to make sure I haven't already included some rewrites for Extended Latin characters and I should be looking at mod_rewrite instead of php, but it turned out that there weren't any and (thankfully) I wasn't as daft as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured most of this out now.

---

I'll tackle the second question to begin with:

> Is it impossible to have URL foldernames and filenames which have
>   percent-encoding already hardcoded into them?

**TLDR:**

As far as I can tell, **yes**. It is impossible.

---

**Explanation:**

If I upload a folder named `/fu%C3%9Fg%C3%A4ngerbr%C3%BCcke/` to my Apache web server, Apache will regard the foldername as a normal ASCII string which does not need escaping... oh, except for the fact that it contains `%` signs.

Which it will escape.

So Apache will now regard the folder name as:

```
/fu%25C3%259Fg%25C3%25A4ngerbr%25C3%25BCcke/
```

Every `%` is now transformed into a `%25`. This is why any attempt to point the browser at

- `/fu%C3%9Fg%C3%A4ngerbr%C3%BCcke/`; or
- `/fußgängerbrücke/`

will result in a `404`.

I finally saw this explained in [a discussion between *@Marcelo Cantos* and *@Tom* on Stack Overflow in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964193/url-percent-encoding-is-not-working)

---

Now for the first question:

> Does `file_get_contents()` automatically percent-encode extended Latin
>   characters which then need to be explicitly percent-decoded again?

Close, but not quite.

**TLDR:**

It's not `file_get_contents()` that is the issue here but `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

---

**Explanation:**

Once I have uploaded `/fußgängerbrücke/` to my Apache server, here's what the PHP super global variable `$_SERVER` reports when the browser is currently pointing at `/fußgängerbrücke/index.php`:

- `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` returns `/fußgängerbrücke/index.php`

and when the browser is pointing at a new page, after arriving from `/fußgängerbrücke/index.php`:

- `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` returns `https://example.com/fu%C3%9Fg%C3%A4ngerbr%C3%BCcke/`

So, yes, the answer is that even though the foldername, really is `/fußgängerbrücke/`, PHP will report, via `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, that the referrer's name was `/fu%C3%9Fg%C3%A4ngerbr%C3%BCcke/`.

Of course, if you *then* try to `file_get_contents()` from that address, Apache will interpret it as `/fu%25C3%259Fg%25C3%25A4ngerbr%25C3%25BCcke/` (see above) and then PHP will tell you the latter doesn't exist.

Comment: The list of characters that are valid for a folder name are not the same as the ones that are valid in a URL. Since the referrer header contains a URL, you should expect them to be encoded to make them valid. Reading data from the file system using a path built from unreliable user-provided data such as the referrer is inherently risky, so I hope you have a bit more validation than you've included in your question.

Comment: In this case the script is being run in a PHP-powered CSS file. I need to know the HTML page which is calling that file, hence my deployment of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Answer (score 0):

You have your own solution by using  `urldecode()` From the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) `urldecode decodes any %## encoding in the given string. Plus symbols ('+') are decoded to a space character.`

Comment: Yes, I already had it working using `urldecode()`. My issue wasn't getting it to work but figuring out what was going on under the hood that I would ever need to use `urldecode()` in the first place. It turns out (see my answer) that the culprit is `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.